# Взаимодействие с базой через нестандартный порт

Tags: база-данных

Друзья подскажите пожалуйста такая ситуация:
Разрабатываю клиент-серверное(двухзвенка клиент-СУБД) приложение, но в организации заблокированы практически все порты в т.ч для работы с СУБД. Есть вариант настроить работу СУБД через нестандартный открытый порт(например 80), но не знаю хорошая ли это практика.. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Спросить товарищей, которые заведуют блокировкой портов, нет? А держать открытым порт 80 - это откровенно плохая практика.

Comment: И кстати разные СУБД работают по разному. некоторым одного порта не достаточно...

Comment: @VTT Дело в том, что это не так-то просто и рассматриваю какой-нибудь обходной путь

Comment: @Mike А если я использую MS SQL, достаточно ли будет перенастроить порт?